# Magento 2 How to disable html date input type in choosing future dates?

Tags: magento2, datepicker

I am trying to disable future dates in my Magento custom modal. here is my script. I work perfectly fine in my html file. But when I apply it in Magento, it does not work.

Can someone suggest a better solution? Thanks.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var todaysDate = new Date();
        var year = todaysDate.getFullYear();
        var month = ("0" + (todaysDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var day = ("0" + todaysDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var maxDate = (year +"-"+ month +"-"+ day);
        $('#customer-bday').attr('max',maxDate);
    });
});
```

Comment: try changing 'max' to 'maxDate' and check..

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by changing the `type="date"` to `type="text"` and with this code

```
require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/calendar"
    ], function ($) {
        $("#customer-bday").calendar({
            showsTime: false,
            hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
            maxDate: new Date(),
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        });
    });
```

Works well.